# Can I browse local Google Datastore emulator data for node.js project?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a node.js project I am deploying to Google Compute Engine (not App Engine). I use the datastore emulator locally. I know one typical way to browse the local datastore emulator data is by using the dev_appserver.py and browsing to http://localhost:8000/datastore

However, I'm not using one of the supported runtimes for the Local Development Server.

Is there a way to browse the local datastore emulator data when using node.js?

Answer (score 0):

Via a ready made UI? No.

You could instead run queries against it to browse the data. Using the Node.js client library, just point the client library to localhost:8080.

```
var datastore = require('@google-cloud/datastore')({
  projectId: 'your-project-id',
  keyFilename: '/path/to/keyfile.json',
  apiEndpoint: 'http://localhost:8080'
});
```

Comment: Yes, via a UI or CLI or something, something more "browsable" than querying via a node app. I'm already going to be running queries against it from my app because I'm obviously going to consume the data. I was indeed looking more for something like the local dev server's data browser so I could verify that I'm seeing what I think I'm putting in. Or wondering if I could spin that up along side using the go or python runtime but still access the other local emulator datastore that I'm saving via my node app maybe.